# Why is the Context Menu not Showing up in ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, contextmenu

I want to display a context menu on long click, on the ListView item in Search Result Activity, i've used "registerForContextMenu(View v)" function and also overridden the context menu creation method, but is context menu is not being generated and "onCreateContextMenu" method is not being called. please Explain the reason . here is my Java code for activity containing the ListView :

```
    public class WeatherSearch extends ListActivity implements WeatherServiceCallback {   

    private String query;
    private OpenWeatherService service;
    private ListView L;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_weather_search);
        handleIntent(getIntent());
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String query = intent.getStringExtra("query");
        service=new OpenWeatherService(this,getBaseContext(),"SEARCH",query,null);
        service.refreshWeather();
        l=(ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        handleIntent(intent);
    }

    private void handleIntent(Intent intent) {
        try {
            if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
                    //use the query to search
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();};
    }

    @Override
    public void serviceSuccess(JSONObject obj) {
        searchResultParser prs=new searchResultParser();
        try {
            prs.populate(obj);
        }catch(Exception e){};
        WeatherAdapter adp = new     WeatherAdapter(this,R.layout.list,R.id.text,prs.getList());
        l.setAdapter(adp);
        registerForContextMenu(l);
    }

    @Override
    public void serviceFailure(Exception exp) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location Search Failed ! ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_location_set_context, menu);
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu,v,menuInfo);
        if (v.getId()==android.R.id.list) {
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo)menuInfo;
            menu.clearHeader();
            menu.add(Menu.NONE, 0, 0, "Set as Default Location");
        }
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected (MenuItem item){
        return true;
    }}
```

HERE my XML code for WeatherSearch Activity :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.adeel.openweatherprework.WeatherSearch"
    android:background="@drawable/weather_bkg1">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/forecastLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ListView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:dividerHeight="2dp"
            android:divider="#FFFFFF" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

HERE is the List XML used in custom List Adapter :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:onClick="clicked"
        android:paddingBottom="12dp"
        android:paddingTop="12dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

HERE is Context Menu XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/context_menu"
        android:title="@string/Loc_settings" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to inflate your menu first

```
@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.my_menu_context, menu);
// Rest of your code goes here
}
```

also you need a menu too:

my_menu_context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:id="@+id/menu_item_delete"
android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_delete"
android:title="@string/delete_item" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Done , still nothing , code has also been update above

Comment: are you sure that your "serviceSuccess" is called in the context of your onCreate??

Comment: not exactly , ServiceSuccess is executed as a callback function after execution of AsyncTask. in OnCreate Method , right in the second Last line ; service.refreshWeather() starts an AsyncTask as a new Thread , upon end of which , serviceSuccess is calledback from passed reference. so apparently serviceSucess will be called after execution of onCreate

Answer (score 0):

I addedd this line in longClick event and it run with me.
 openContextMenu(adapterView);

with this you can handle onlongClick event and onContextItemSelected.

Comment: It's advisable to add some context or example code to support your answer.